# Healthkit on iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios7, ios8

How to support iOS7 is my question.What I mean is not to make HealthKit work on iOS7,but to make it work on iOS8 and don't crash in iOS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HealthKit is in iOS8 SDK. So you cant support it for iOS7..

if you want to do any separate code for iOS8 you can do as below.

```
// Above ios 8.0
float os_version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (os_version >= 8.000000)
{
   　　　//Your Code for iOS8
}
else
{
     //  Your Code for previous version    
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I got it.Maybe I should make this APP iOS8 only=.=

Comment: Yes. you should make your apps only for iOS8..
if my answer helped u, then please give vote or mark as answer..

Comment: Checkout this very basic blog post about integrating HealthKit. Maybe it will help you to some extent http://jademind.com/blog/posts/healthkit-api-tutorial/